# Flex-box, navigation menu and responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation menu that resizes on specific window sizes. Works quite well but I have a problem where the navigation list centers in it's parent div but the logo in the same div doesn't. Here are the codes:

HTML

```
<nav id="top_menu">
    <div id="logo"> <img src="images/logo.svg"> </div>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li data-slide="1">Home</li>
        <li data-slide="2">Skills</li>
        <li data-slide="3">Over mij</li>
        <li data-slide="4">Portfolio</li>
        <li data-slide="5">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (Sass with Bourbon mixins)

```
// NAVIGATION

#top_menu {
@include display(flex);
@include flex-flow(row wrap);
@include justify-content(flex-start);
@include align-content(center);
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
background-color: white;
height: 80px;
z-index: 1;

@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
    height: 60px;
    top: 36px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    top: 0;
    height: auto;
    @include flex-flow(column wrap);
    @include justify-content(center);
    @include align-content(center);
}
}

#logo {
display: block;
margin-left: 3%;
width: 12%;
max-width: 150px;
min-width: 100px;

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

}

.navigation{
width: 82%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;

@include display(flex);
@include flex-flow(row wrap);
@include justify-content(flex-start);
@include align-content(center);

//@media all and (max-width:800px) {
//  @include justify-content(space-around);
//}

@media all and (max-width:960px) {
    width: 75%;
    @include justify-content(space-around);
}

@media all and (max-width:640px) {
    width: auto;
    @include flex-flow(column wrap);
    padding: 0;
}

li {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
padding: 10px;

font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 40px;

@media all and (max-width:960px) {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

@media all and (max-width:640px) {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

    &:hover,&.active {
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px 0px rgba(245, 86, 78, 1);
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor:pointer;

        @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px 0px rgba(245, 86, 78, 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I've found out so far is that it doesn't really put the two div's below each other; changing the width of the navigation to something lower or higher changes the position of the logo. I can't however find how to solve this and get the logo to stick above the navigation in a centered position. I like flex-box a lot, but it's somewhat difficult to understand sometimes. What am I doing wrong here?

You can see the problem here: http://de-kleijn.com/test/ndk/

Comment: i tried copy/paste in code pen , but Sass with Bourbon mixins has errors there

Comment: *All* of this code is necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yeah sorry for all the code, will keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the align-content property when you need to be using align-items.  Align-items is for controlling how items are aligned on the same row.  Align-content is for controlling how the rows are aligned relative to the other rows.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/yAIKs

```
.navigation{
  width: 82%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid;

  @include display-flex;
  @include flex-flow(row wrap);
  @include justify-content(flex-start);
  @include align-items(center);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`flex-box` is quiet knew and not that solid yet, i would use `display:table` wich works from IE8.
 here's an example , with changes to fix behavior of image and li font-size.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fktCL

```
#top_menu {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  background:gray linear-gradient(to bottom, #555 , #eee);
  padding:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
}
#logo , .navigation{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height:0;
  width:18%;
}
.navigation {
  width:82%;
}
.navigation li {
  display:inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.navigation:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:250px;;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
  display:block;
  margin: 2px auto;
}
@media all and (max-width:960px) {
  #logo , .navigation
  {
    display:block;
    font-size:0.8em;
    width:100%;
  }
  #logo img {
    width:100px;}
}
```

code updated to resize image untill menu drops down

Comment: Table rows cannot wrap, though.

Comment: ?? the idea is to see them on top of each other once width is too small , or did i misunderstand what the op is looking after ?

Comment: I know it's quite new, and really considered using this or not. However, a bit futher on the page I needed flexbox to pull something off that can't be done without using javascript/jQuery. Besides, it's not really a problem for now that people with < IE10 can't view this. Maybe I'm going to create a fallback later ;) Thanks tho!

Comment: for ie' you may make a fallback with display:table & CO or  inline-block/inline/zoom , using display:table gives, at this time, less code to tune :)